# Prevent deleting feedback messages on refresh in Wicket

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, wicket, feedbackpanel

I would like to maintain the error messages, which are generated at the page load up, even when the user refreshes the page. I can let them stay by saving them globally and then reenter them in the `FeedBackPanel` inside of page's `renderHead` method, but when I get back to the previous page for example, the error is still there, until I refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can register a IFeedbackMessageFilter with IApplicationSettiongs#setFeedbackMessageCleanupFilter() - this way you can control which messages will be cleaned up after each request.